# How can I set date on Alarmmanger?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, alarmmanager

I have tried this code to alarm at March first. 
But It doesn't work.
How can I solve this problem?

*Content of APP*

---

When we press the button(click1), if it was on March first, Alarmmanger calls intent.
so this application prints new Activity.

---

*ERROR*

---

When we press the button(click1), then anytime Alarmmanger calls intent.

---

HOW CAN I SOLVE IT??

-SORRY FOR MY NOT GOOD ENGLISH.. ㅠㅠ

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private AlarmManager alarm;

private NotificationManager notification;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}
    public void click1(View v) {
    notification = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());


    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(cal.YEAR,3,1);


    setAlarm();
    }



private void setAlarm(){

alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent());


}
private PendingIntent pendingIntent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    return p;

}
```

Comment: This may be not your problem but March value is 2. To avoid this type of mistakes use Calendar constants, in this case `Calendar.MARCH`

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need create another Calendar only to obtain the actual year.
When you ask for a new instance of Calendar it will be initialized with the actual date and time
Try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
calendar.set(year,Calendar.MARCH,1);
```

One other thing, if you set the alarm to a past time, the alarm always will go off.

Comment: What it does not work? Edit your question and try to explain the problem better

Comment: oh! I missed the last sentence!

Comment: Pleasure helping you out. If your problem got solved You must accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.MARCH , 1 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

## Avoid old date-time classes

You are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.MARCH , 1 );
```

You can pass a number instead of a `Month` enum object, numbered sanely 1-12 for January-December.

## Time zone

For an alarm we need a time-of-day. You can get the first moment of the day. This is usually the time `00:00:00`, but not always due to to Daylight Saving Time (DST) or other anomalies. Let java.time determine the time.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Apply a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

If your alarm library requires this moment be represented as a count of milliseconds since the epoch of start of 1970 UTC, interrogate for a `long` integer from an extracted [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.